# Requirejs - versioning

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Quick note - by versioning I mean for the purposes of cache busting. The common practice of adding query params to the end of the script request does not work on all browsers. The easiest and the most messiest way that I have found to date is to version my entire deploy folder name.

```
-- scripts.v1
-- scripts.v2
```

But this is incredibly messy and mucks up the deploy times too (I use S3 as my cdn). Does anyone know of an alternate method to this?

### EDIT

It seems, I have not been very clear. Let me be a bit more explicit.

I use requirejs on my site. It is quite a JavaScript heavy application with frequent updates and iterations. With requirejs in place now, the only way I can reliably make sure that browsers are serving the latest version, is to version my whole deploy folder name (javascript) and upload the whole lot of files to S3 again. I then use the `data-main` method to set the base path of the project.

For many reason, this is quite cumbersome. Even if the code change is just a few lines, the whole process has to be repeated. Is there some other decent method to let requirejs know that files have versions? As in, if I call

```
require(["superImportantJSFile"], function(){})
```

it will know that the current version is `superImportantJSFile.v4.js` or something along those lines.

I hope I have been more clear now. Any suggestions as to how the community in general does this? I'm pretty sure this has to be a common scenario, but I haven't been able to find a good solution to this yet

Comment: Can you please explain what it has to do with requireJS in you case.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle I've updated my question, does it make better sense now?

Comment: Interesting question. I think you should consider a more robust build process (check out Yeoman and Grunt in specific). You can easily automate all these 'cumbersome tasks'. In bigger I alternate between CDN locations to make sure all the users get the same versions - of course you should consider doing this for isolated modules (that is, there is no need to do this for your external dependencies (like require itself) most of the time, so it should be in a different folder).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I do use Grunt, it's a life saver. How do you propose I go about my build process?

Comment: @JibiAbraham The simples thing you can do is use something like `grunt-ver` . Honestly I did the automation here myself but I've heard of people having good luck with it. The entire build process itself is very complicated and application dependent - it depends on your specific case and I doubt it'll get a specific answer here. I'm sure people will show up and answer this question in more clever ways. I just write automation for the code that does versioning once when I start a project and stick with it, not sure what the 'idiomatic' way is.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'll take a look at it, tx

Comment: You can use ```urlArgs``` to specify the version number in your script request. Something like ```var require = { urlArgs: 'version=2.0' };``` should work. Then you'll need to handle these requests in your back-end code.

Comment: @DzulqarnainNasir The urlargs/query params won't bust the cache in all browswers

Answer (score 3):

The [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://github.com/h5bp) offers one of the most graceful solutions I have seen. They have configs available for [Apache](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/5370479476dceae7cc3ea105946536d6bc0ee468/.htaccess#L403) and [nginx](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/master/h5bp/location/cache-busting.conf). From there you can just add a timestamp to the filename within your `script` tags, like so:

```
<script src="scripts/app.20130728.js"></script>
```

Which the web server would rewrite to `scripts/app.js`.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use a post-build step that puts static resources into a folder with a path that includes the version control version number.  For example source control revision number 1234 would lead to the creation of a path: /1234/scripts/*.  These directories are also created in the CDN with the correct version of the assets within.

In our require.js config in a template, we replace the baseURL with the appropriate revision, which is controlled via a config file, eg:

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: "%%resDir%%",
    ...
};
```

This makes it easy to change the asset versions between a few different releases, which can all stay on the CDN without causing any conflicts. It also solves the browser cache busting issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can add aliases to your RequireJS configuration by using `map` (see http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map) for example:

```
require.config({ /* ... other config.... */
     map: { '*': {'superImportantJSFile': 'superImportantJSFile.v4'} }
})
```

So you only have one place to update :)

You mentioned the use of a CDN which is a good use case to not put those files in your minimized `r.js` bundle (in case that you are using that tool). But if those files are updated frequently, maybe it makes sense to pack your modules with `r.js` and update the whole code.